# Starting a java GUI program via .cmd file from java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to start a java GUI program in windows via java code as below :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", 
        "C:\\path\\to\\program\\program.cmd"}));
        try {
            builder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The cmd file starts the program with a `"start javaw .."` command with `... -cp program.jar -jar program.jar` . When using the java code above, it throws an error that the program.jar is not found :

[image]

I also tried with the below, using `cd` first :

```
{"cmd.exe", "/C", "cd C:\\path\\to\\program\\ && program.cmd"}));
```

But the above does nothing at all.

Content of .cmd :

```
setlocal

SET JAVAHOME=..\java  
SET PATH=%JAVAHOME%\jre\bin;%JAVAHOME%\jre\bin\client;%JAVAHOME%\bin;%PATH%    
SET PATH=%PATH%;bin\ 
SET POLICY=java.policy 
SET JAR_BOOT=program.jar 
SET CONFIG_FILE=program.xml

IF EXIST jar\%JAR_BOOT% copy jar\%JAR_BOOT% . >NUL

start javaw -Xbootclasspath/p:jar/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;jar/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;jar/xalan-2.7.1m1.jar;jar/serializer-2.7.1m.jar -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=200M -cp %JAR_BOOT% -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE -Djava.security.policy=%POLICY% -jar %JAR_BOOT%

title Command Prompt 
endlocal
```

So what's the proper way to do this ?

Comment: Show us the content of the command file.

Comment: You are swallowing the exception in catch - so I would at least print it so you know what error occurred

Comment: Also, `builder.start()` returns a Process object, and you'll want to capture this process's Streams, *especially* the ErrorStream to allow the OS to tell you if anything untoward is happening. Also capture the InputStream and handle it so as not to clog up the process's buffer.

Comment: @Sergi, not swallowing it, I do print it I just ommitted it in the question. In any case, I see no exception raised in both cases.

Comment: content of .cmd added

Comment: @Hovercraft I tried to capture the ErrorStream but I see no output in both cases : `Process p = builder.start();
            InputStream error = p.getErrorStream();
             for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {
                System.out.println("" + error.read());
             }`

Comment: Your jar path is relative. Therefore you have to set the working directory, otherwise the path to the jar file will be incorrect: `builder.directory(..)`.

Comment: @JMax it worked just fine with your suggestion, many thanks! Please feel free to post it as an aswer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @JMax to use the `directory()` method of the ProcessBuilder to set the working directory has fixed the issue